# How to delete rows based on columns' value?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete rows based on one columns value! But the column length of the range in the worksheet is dynamic and large.

For example,
If Col C has value less than or equal to 0 that row gets deleted

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SAM | 100 |
| 1 | SAM | 0 |
| 1 | BRI | -100 |
| 1 | HAWK | 100 |

It should only give me :

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SAM | 100 |
| 1 | HAWK | 100 |

Comment: First of all, you are inputting 0 as string, it should be `Cell.Value <= 0`. Second, when deleting rows, it's indeed better to go backwards. Start from last row and go to first deleting.

Comment: Also change `Range(Cell.Address)` to just `Cell`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as said in my comment,try this:

```
Sub test()
Dim LR As Long
Dim i As Long

LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'get last non blank row number

For i = LR To 1 Step -1 'go backwards starting at LR until row 1
    If Range("C" & i).Value <= 0 Then Range("C" & i).EntireRow.Delete
Next i


End Sub
```

Before code:

[image]

After code executed:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, your way is simpler I tried this but it isnt working! No error nothing, can you please see what I am missing? Thanks again, edited the question!

Comment: Although often used to figure out the last row `Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` fails when data is filtered - it will return the last *visible* row with data.

Comment: For me right now it will be okay because I am calling it in the function while pasting the original values, so I only need to run it the first time I copy it but please if you know a better way?

Comment: Thank you it worked, I tried to run it in a module instead of VBA sheet! My bad :)